# Changing active state to a random <li> on load of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a demo in JS Bin.

http://jsbin.com/ivigab/1/

What I would like to do is quite simple, I would like to be able to click to one li and give it a class of active and have the the child div fade in. All this would happen in reverse for the previous active li at the same time too if possible.

Also as the title states, I would like to change the active li to be random each time a user views the page, is this possible?

B

Comment: Are you looking for something like an [accordian](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)? If this is what you want I can tell you how to randomize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really simple example but should give you the desired result:-

```
$('#entries li').click(function() {

  // remove active class and fade div out from all list elements
  $('#entries li').removeClass('active');
  $('#entries div').fadeOut();

  // add active class to the clicked element and fade the div in
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('div', this).fadeIn();    

});

// generate a random number ranging between 0 and the number of available li's
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#entries li').length);

// trigger the click event on the random element
$('#entries li').eq(random).trigger('click');
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkPaW/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://jsbin.com/exasej/1/edit) it should do what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $entries = $('#entries a');
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*$entries.length)

  $entries.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $li = $this.parent();
    var activeEntry = $this.parents('#entries').find('li.active');
    activeEntry.find('div').fadeOut(300);
    activeEntry.removeClass('active');

    $li.find('div').fadeIn(300);
    $li.addClass('active');
  });

  $entries.eq(randomNumber).click();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is exactly what I wanted, but deifwud made the same implementation in less code.